# Can I set variable as data type length in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, types, sqldatatypes, variable-length

I have a variable that is a hex with reversed bytes. To reverse bytes I found the solution with type binary and reversing it depends on its size. Since I have to reverse bytes of variable @card which can be different sizes I was thinking of declaring variable @binarylen, type int, which I want to set as data type length but get an error 'incorrect syntax: expecting ID, INTEGER or QOUTED_ID'. Can I somehow do this?

```
DECLARE @card_hex nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @card_int bigint
DECLARE @badgenr nvarchar(max)
set @badgenr= '120224205061286445' 

-- convert it to hex
        set @card_int = convert (bigint, (@badgenr))
        print @card_int
        set @card_hex = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(31),CONVERT(VARBINARY, @card_int),2)
        print @card_hex

--remove leading zeroes:
set @card_hex = (select substring(@card_hex, patindex('%[^0]%',@card_hex), 20))
print @card_hex

DECLARE @bitelen as int
set @bitelen= LEN(@card_hex)

declare @binarylen as int
set @binarylen=@bitelen/2 + @bitelen%2

declare @reverse as binary(@binarylen)
set @reverse=( SELECT cast(reverse(cast(@card_int AS BINARY(@binarylen))) AS BINARY(@binarylen)))
```

Comment: Since it's `varbinary` simply use some length that is a bit more than the maximum length you expect.

Comment: To answer the question, no you can't use a variable to define a variable or in fact anything that needs to be defined using a literal.

Comment: All types in T-SQL have pre-defined (maximum) sizes, even if the value contained within them can be of variable length. Only the built-in functions can return different types based on their input type, an ability which is not available to user-defined functions. The only concession T-SQL makes to "flexible" typing is `SQL_VARIANT`, which however is largely useless as it requires you to already know the correct type in it before you can effectively use it, or else get funky with dynamic SQL.

Comment: I tried to declare @binarylen as SQL_VARIANT because I know it has to be type INT (you can see it in the code above) but I have the error saying I'm using wrong syntax because I can't declare a variable as binary(select cast(@binarylen as int))

Comment: I only mentioned `SQL_VARIANT` for completeness. You cannot solve your problem with it. There is no T-SQL syntax for creating a value of a type with a specific length at runtime (except for dynamic SQL, which is not accessible in functions). You can always just use `VARBINARY(MAX)` and accept that the code using it will have to take care of casting it to something more specific if required. Speaking of which -- [do not use `VARBINARY` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) (the link talks about `NVARCHAR` but it's the same thing).

Comment: It seems that in @badgenr you have the digits of a number that fits in a bigint. In this case you can use binary(8), because bigint has 8 bytes.